# state update from a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop

The following member function populates asynchronously a `folder_structure` object with fake data:

```js
    fake(folders_: number, progress_callback_: (progress_: number) => void = (progress_: number) => null): Promise<boolean>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for (let i_ = 0; i_ < folders_; i_++) {
                progress_callback_(i_ / folders_ * 100.);

                this.add(this.id(), faker.address.city() + i_, random_choice(this.folder_structure_id()));
            }

            progress_callback_(folders_ / folders_ * 100.);

            resolve(true);
        })
    }
```

It uses a callback to update the progress within the `for` loop which is then used to update the state (a progress bar) from within a `useEffect()` function with an empty dependency array.

```js
   let [progress_state_, set_progress_state_] = useState<number>(0);

   let [fake_done_, set_fake_done_] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        if (fake_)
            folder_structure_.fake(fake_, (progress_) => {
                set_progress_state_(progress_)
            }).then(value => set_fake_done_(value));
    }, [])

    if (!fake_ || fake_done_) etc etc
```

However, the state is not updated (logging the progress in the console seems to work fine). Any ideas as to whether it's possible to update a state from within `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `useEffect` hook isn't working is that it's not called upon `progress_state_` state change.

Instead of

```
useEffect(() =>
    {
        ...
    }, [])
```

**Try this instead**

```
useEffect(() =>
    {
        ...
    }, [progress_])
```

Adding `progress_` to the dependency array means `useEffect` will be called every single time `progress_` changes. If you leave it as an empty dependency array, then `useEffect` is only ever called in the very beginning on when the code is mounted to the DOM.

Here's a good explanation on dependency arrays: https://devtrium.com/posts/dependency-arrays

Comment: The state is being updated from within the callback, ```useEffect``` only needs to be called once, to register the callback

Answer (score -1):

Addressing your final question: Yes, it *is* possible to update state from within `useEffect`.

To understand the root of your main issue, I would be curious to see how you are doing your logging. Are you logging from within `fake()` or from your `render()` function?

Comment: `console.log()` is called from within the callback right below the `set_progress_state` that is used to update the state. It just seems that the state update is not enough to rerender the component, something that becomes apparent if I put some naked logging code anywhere within the function that is supposed to be called on every render.

Comment: for the record:

` folder_structure_.fake(fake_, (progress_) => {
                set_progress_state_(progress_);

                console.log(progress_state_);
                console.log(progress_);
`

outputs:
0 for the state and normal progress via the callback

Comment: Are you saying that it only outputs `0` once for each `console.log()`?
Or is it outputting multiple `0`s since the callback function would be called multiple times?

Comment: It outputs the correct progress when it comes to the progress passed by the callback but 0 when I log the state which means the state is not updated. Interestingly enough if I delay the set_fake_done using a timeout for say 1 second, I do get the progress updates which I attribute to the asynchronous nature of setting the state in React. Which also means it's not very easy to update with the progress of time consuming tasks